# Is There a Font Demo App for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, fonts

On iOS, you can easily get all the available Fonts via `[UIFont familyNames]`. The method returns an array, so it would sure be easy to create a little App that displayed all the available fonts in a `UITableView` and would show which fonts every "family" has in a `DetailViewController`.

Before I go ahead and code something like this I wanted to ask whether anyone knew if Apple or anybody else provides such a font demo app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is - it's called Fonts.

Comment: I have FontPicker installed, which works sufficiently well that I haven't checked out the other options.

Answer (score 1):

[iFonts](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ifonts/id392614957?mt=8) displays the fonts in a table view. You can also use it to email the list of fonts to yourself or someone else on your team.

Disclaimer: I developed it.